# Python 2.7 class that maintains only max and min of inserted values

Tags: python, collections

Is there a readily available Python 2.7 class/container/collection that stores only the max and min of inserted values? Example usage:

```
arr = Class()
arr.append(1)
arr.append(2)
arr.append(3)
print arr.max(), arr.min()
```

should return

```
3 1
```

Comment: There is no builtin container which keeps only min and max. Why would you want that? There is probably a better solution for your actual problem, e.g. `print min(arr), max(arr)`, where arr is any kind of container.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one in the standard library, but it's easy to write one:

```
class MinMaxCollection:

    def init(self, seq = None):
        self._minmax = None
        if seq is not None:
            for elem in seq:
                self.add(elem)

    def add(self, elem):
        if self._minmax is None:
            self._minmax = ( elem, elem )
        else:
            self._minmax = ( min(self._minmax[0], elem), max(self._minmax[1], elem) )

    def minmax(self):
        if self._minmax is None:
            raise ValueError('Empty')
        return self._minmax

    def min(self):
        return self.minmax()[0]
    def max(self):
        return self.minmax()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Numpy arrays. You can do this with the [`amax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html) and [`amin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

What are you needing it for?  The problem is pretty trivial to solve, and can be done a couple of ways depending on the requirements.  If you want to store only the min and max values, and ignore everything else that has been inserted the following will work.  It's O(1) too since you aren't storing the old values.  If you need to have a running record of all the values, I would have an internal array that is sorted.  Then you can just pop the head for the smallest or pop the tail for the largest.

```
class MinMax:
    def __init__(self):
        self.min = None
        self.max = None

    def append(self, val):
        if self.min is None or self.min > val:
            self.min = val
        if self.max is None or self.max < val:
            self.max = val

    def getMin(self):
        return self.min

    def getMax(self):
        return self.max
```